# How to set the title of a taskbaricon in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython, win32gui, taskkill

I create a taskbar icon like this:

```
class TaskBarIcon(wx.adv.TaskBarIcon):
def __init__(self, frame):
    self.frame = frame
    super(TaskBarIcon, self).__init__()
    self.set_icon(TRAY_ICON)
    self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_left_down)

def CreatePopupMenu(self):
    menu = wx.Menu()
    create_menu_item(menu, 'Site', self.on_hello)
    menu.AppendSeparator()
    create_menu_item(menu, 'Exit', self.on_exit)
    return menu

def set_icon(self, path):
    icon = wx.Icon(path)
    self.SetIcon(icon, TRAY_TOOLTIP)

def on_left_down(self, event):      
    print ('Tray icon was left-clicked.')

def on_hello(self, event):
    print ('Hello, world!')

def on_exit(self, event):
    wx.CallAfter(self.Destroy)
    self.frame.Close()

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame=wx.Frame(None, title="testit")
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        TaskBarIcon(frame) # removing this line changes the window title properly
        return True


app = App(False)
app.MainLoop()
```

The problem I have is that I want to set the title of the application and later kill the application with `taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq testit"`. If I remove the line `TaskBarIcon(frame)` this `taskkill` command works, but it says no tasks matching specified criteria otherwise. How can I change the window title of my application but still create a task bar icon?

Note, this might be possible with something like [this](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/SysTrayIcon.py.html), but I prefer to use wxpython over such a low level API.

Comment: I'm not convinced a TaskBarIcon has a `title` as such, at least not on Linux, it's tucked away in the System Tray. You have to search for `python3 scriptname` to get the PID and then kill that.

Comment: what I ended up doing is creating the tray icon as a subprocess using multiprocessing...when you say searching what exactly are you searching to get the PID? I'm thinking you mean taskkill /IM "python 3 test.py" but I this doesn't seem to actually find the process on Windows

Comment: I haven't used Windows in decades but there must be a way to find the PID of a process. Try `taskkill /IM "python3.exe test.py"` or whatever the python's exe filename is. It'll have a PID the trick is to find it. try importing `os` then store `os.getpid()` somewhere you can access it later from your kill script.

Comment: The process is "python.exe" but the script name isn't included (so taskkill /IM python.exe works but would kill all python processes). I think on Linux what you're suggesting would work but I'm not seeing an easier way than what I did for Windows so far. Maybe if I could set some other property on the process and find it programmatically that way but I'm not sure what property I would set

Comment: Will the `os.getpid()` route not work, or does that stray off your methodology too far?

Comment: I can use `os.getpid()` but the problem is that it's supposed to kill another instance of the script on startup if it exists, so I'd have to either persist the PID to disk or have the process create a small local server that will send the PID over when requested (on a predefined port), or use something like Apache Arrow to share the data between processes. Unless I find an easy way to programmatically identify the application (other than the window title which I'm currently using and is working, just kinda ugly to get working) then I don't think it's worth using `os.getpid()`

Comment: Is there a reason you have to kill a currently running instance, rather than prevent the new instance if one is currently running?

Comment: It's more convenient when I'm making updates to the program because I just run the new copy.